# Remove Duplicates in dynamic row and column ranges

Tags: excel, vba

How do I allow for dynamic ranges?

Here is the sample macro I recorded in Excel that I am working with:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
Cells.Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$87").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3), _
Header:=xlNo
End Sub
```

How can I edit this to allow for varying row and column counts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
ActiveSheet.Columns(1).Resize(, 3).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3), Header:=xlNo
```

Or

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3), Header:=xlNo
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing anything about how your data is organized:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.RemoveDuplicates _
                      Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3), _ Header:=xlNo
```

Comment: Sorry for the vague post.  What information should I include?

Comment: You could add something outlining what you mean by "dynamic".  Requirements for varying row count are pretty straightforward, but for varying columns a little less so.

Comment: I would like to allow for varying row and column counts.

Comment: Yes.  This one worked:  ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3), Header:=xlNo  Thank you!