# Removing duplicates in sheets, each sheet with a different sized range of data

Tags: excel, vba

I've an Excel spreadsheet with seven sheets, each sheet with a different sized range of data.

I would like to remove duplicate rows.

I tried various bits of code from across the internet. I always get:

> Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

The seven sheets pull data from our ERP system once a day, through an SQL query. I then use Power Automate Desktop to automatically copy all the information from the Excel workbook to another Excel workbook, as values so that I can share the information without other people being able to edit the properties of the query.

The data from the original Excel workbook contains duplicates. I need a macro that Power Automate can run to remove those duplicates from each sheet within the second workbook.

In regards to code I tried lots of combinations, and can't remember them all. I tried:

```vb
Sub sbRemoveDuplicatesSpecificWithNoHeaders()

Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("A1:D" & LastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(3), Header:= xlYes

End Sub
```

A couple links I've tried code from:

[Remove Duplicates in dynamic row and column ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959343/remove-duplicates-in-dynamic-row-and-column-ranges)

https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/removing-duplicate-values/

Answer (score 0):

As you download the tables from ERP I assume the columns remain the same while the number of rows varies.

With PowerQuery it is rather simple:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/keep-or-remove-duplicate-rows-power-query-d9cffc69-dc5d-4d94-8b66-72779688874d

You may want to use Power Automate to download and save to the Source.xlsx file and have the Clean.xlsx including the PowerQuery code to open/connect to the Source.xlsx as source and to remove the duplicates; run PowerQuery each time you open or refresh in Clean.xlsx